# Is there a way to view how close we are to the throttling limit for Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure-keyvault

We recently had a poorly-written service that called the Azure Key Vault APIs so frequently that we hit our vault and subscription level [service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-service-limits).

After spending a significant amount of time looking in the Azure Portal, it would seem the only way to track call and throttling volume is per Key Vault, and the useful details are only surfaced when connecting diagnostic logging. This really only helps after the issue has occurred, as it is a nontrivial cost to leave diagnostic logging configured on every Key Vault all the time.

Is there any way to view ongoing Key Vault request consumption compared to request limits, both per vault and at the subscription level?

Comment: The Azure Keyvault logging docs can be found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-logging
This should monitor all your keyvault accesses. Is there anything in the Keyvault Logging docs that don't answer your question?

Comment: Right, but that is the diagnostic logging I'm referring to. I'm looking more for an out-of-the-box, ideally-low-cost solution. Even something similar to the way [ARM Throttling is logged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-request-limits) would be an improvement.